# Nilpotent Operators

Tags: linear-transformations

Let T be a nilpotent operator on an n-dimensional vector space V . Then T^n = 0,
where 0 ∈ L(V ) is the zero map.

(a) First, show that since T is nilpotent, dimkerT > 0.

(b) Next, show that either T is the zero map or dimker T
2 > dimkerT.

(c) Show in general that for k ∈ {2, 3, . . .} either T
k−1
is the zero map or dimker T
k > dimker
T
k−1
.

(d) Using parts (a)-(c), why must T
n = 0?

I am beyond confused with how to solve this proof. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Solution for $a)$ : Since $T$ is nilpotent, the only eigenvalue is $0$. Hence, $T$ is not invertible, implying $kern(T)\ne$ {$0$}